# show my WHMCS admins and clients gravatar

Tags: whmcs

I want show my WHMCS admins and clients gravatar in viewticket page index or ...

How I can do it?

(get admin or client email from database and puting this code)

```
<img class="gravatar" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id={"{$adminemail}"|md5}&amp;s ize=150" alt="Avatar" title="Avatar for {$name}" width="150" height="150" />
```

Answer (score 1):

When using a variable within a smarty expression you don't need to enclose it into curly brackets again, just use it.

`{"{$adminemail}"|md5}` becomes: `{$adminemail|md5}`

Also, you have space in &s ize=150, correct image is:

```
<img class="gravatar" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id={$adminemail|md5}&amp;size=150" alt="Avatar" title="Avatar for {$name}" width="150" height="150" />
```